# Searching datagrid view exact keywords

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagrid

I want to make search results exact.
For example i inputted "L" my program just shows any results that has letter "L" in it instead of showing results that the first letter is "L". so how to do that?

Here's my code:

***before searching or typing on searchbox, user must first choose a radio button to search data from a column, in my program there are 3 radio buttons (ID, Lastname, Firstname)

```
 Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
        Dim DataTable As New DataTable
        Dim DataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=PatientManagementSystem;")
        MySqlConn.Open()
        'SEARCH ID
        If rdbtnID.Checked = True Then
            txtSearch.MaxLength = 9
            With cmd
                .Connection = MySqlConn
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM newpatient WHERE ID like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
            End With
            DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            DataTable.Clear()
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
            dgvRecords.DataSource = DataTable
            MySqlConn.Close()
            'SEARCH LASTNAME
        ElseIf rdbtnLastname.Checked = True Then
            txtSearch.MaxLength = 32767
            With cmd
                .Connection = MySqlConn
                .CommandText = "select * from newpatient where Lastname like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
            End With
            DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            DataTable.Clear()
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
            dgvRecords.DataSource = DataTable
            MySqlConn.Close()
            'SEARCH FIRSTNAME
        ElseIf rdbtnFirstname.Checked = True Then
            txtSearch.MaxLength = 32767
            With cmd
                .Connection = MySqlConn
                .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM newpatient WHERE Firstname like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
            End With
            DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            DataTable.Clear()
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
            dgvRecords.DataSource = DataTable
            MySqlConn.Close()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the % like symbol from the beginning.

Change

```
"SELECT * FROM newpatient WHERE ID like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
```

into:

```
"SELECT * FROM newpatient WHERE ID like '" & txtSearch.Text & "%'"
```

May I also suggest: (1) use parameterized sql if this is a production system, and (2) if you insist on sql concatenation you need to escape any single quotes in txtSearch.Text that the user types into 2 single quotes. Otherwise the sql statements will fail.

Comment: Nice. Don't forget the green tick!

Comment: can I have a green tick please, if this worked for you